# QGIS: Draw adjacency graph for map

Tags: qgis, coordinates, graph

I have a map of the districts of a city. The districts are in a single layer having the properties [fid, name, long, lat]. The values of long and lat are the centroids of the shapes which I calculated with QGIS.

What I really would like to have is drawing a graph where the nodes are the districts, being positioned at the GPS coordinates of the centroids, having the name as a label. The edges should be active between two nodes if they share a border. The latter one might be a bit harder, but since I used the snapping tool when drawing the polygons, I guess that the data is existing.

I know this is a bigger project, but does anyone know if there is a standard procedure, maybe an already existing function in QGIS?

Might there be a different tool or website existing for that purpose? In theory, I only need the table of properties and an addition list which ids are adjacent to each other.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in QGIS but in R:

First of all let's get some polygons (municipality boundaries around Åsane) using `osmdata` package. If you have the data already in form of geopackage or other shapefile, use `st_read()` function from `sf` package.

```r
b <- osmdata::getbb("Åsane", format_out = "sf_polygon") |>
  sf::st_buffer(dist = 20000) |>
  sf::st_bbox() |>
  osmdata::opq() |>
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "boundary", value = "administrative") |>
  osmdata::osmdata_sf()

m <- b$osm_multipolygons |>
  subset(b$osm_multipolygons$admin_level == 7)
```

And visualize it:

```r
tmap::tm_shape(m) +
  tmap::tm_polygons(col = "name") +
  tmap::tm_legend(legend.position = c(0.82,0.0))
```

[image]

Now let's use `spdep` package and 2 functions: `poly2nb()` to construct neighbors list form polygons and `nb2lines() to create the lines between polygons centroids:

```r
nb <- spdep::poly2nb(m)
l <- spdep::nb2lines(nb, coords = sf::st_centroid(sf::st_geometry(m)))

tmap::tm_shape(m) +
  tmap::tm_polygons(col = "name") +
  tmap::tm_shape(l) +
  tmap::tm_lines() +
  tmap::tm_legend(legend.position = c(0.82,0.0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Very nice idea and good code, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Virtual Layer to join the layer to itself by intersecting polygons, where their fids are different. Then create a line between the centroids. Execute the query and tick "Load as new layer"

The layer is temporary, to save it right-click  - Export - Save As.

```sql
select  row_number() over() as id, a.name as name_a, b.name as name_b,
        SetSRID(makeline(st_point(a.long, a.lat), st_point(b.long, b.lat)), 4326) as geometry
from district a
left join district b
on st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry) and a.fid<b.fid
order by a.fid, b.fid
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Very neat code and explanation, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use [Geometry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#hard-fa-geometry-generator-symbology) with the following expression. Instead of centroids, I used the function [`point_on_surface()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#point-on-surface) because depending on the polygon's shape, sometimes its centroid falls outside the polygon. If you want centroids, use [`centroid()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#centroid) instead:

```
collect_geometries (
    array_foreach(
        overlay_touches (
            @layer,  -- replace this with your layer name in single quotes
            point_on_surface ($geometry)
        ),
        make_line(
            point_on_surface ($geometry),
            @element
        )
    )
)
```

If you want to create actual lines, use [Geometry by Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) and change `@layer` in line 4 with the actual layer name in single quotes, e.g. `'polygon'`.

*Red lines, based on the blue polygons with black outline, created with the expression:*
[image]

Comment: Very nice idea and good code, thank you!